# Django form not overwriting previous entry

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am currently using a form in Django to have users enter an API key which is then saved. However. i would like to give users the opportunity to change this key at a later time, or add one if they have already done so. However, when I try to enter a new API key, it does not override the previous entry.

Here is my models.py file:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    quandl_api = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Here is my forms.py file:

```
class ChangeApiForm(forms.ModelForm):
    quandl_api = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('quandl_api',)
```

Here is my views.py file:

```
@login_required
def change_api(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    registered = False

    if request.POST:
        new_api_form = ChangeApiForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if new_api_form.is_valid():
            new_api_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/account')
    else:
        new_api_form = ChangeApiForm()
    return render_to_response('ui/change_api.html', {'new_api_form': new_api_form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

After I submit the form to enter a new API key, the page refreshes and takes me to the "accounts page" as I specified in the views.py file. But the API key there is still the old one.

Comment: Could this be the issue (speculating) - `request.user` evaluates to `User`, however, the modelform is associated with `UserProfile` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be passing the UserProfile object as the instance, not the user.

```
new_api_form = ChangeApiForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.userprofile)
```